# Forgot power on password

Tags: password-recovery

I forgot power on password of my laptop. My laptop is Lenovo G500. 
I have tried everything like removing CMOS, battery supply. Please help me to reset/remove power on password.

Comment: Avinash - I wanted to make sure you knew about [Accepting an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so check it out when you get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

> **Forgot power on password**
>
> I forgot power on password of my laptop. My laptop is Lenovo G500. I
>   have tried everything like removing CMOS, battery supply. Please help
>   me to reset/remove power on password.

As per the [Lenovo User Guide (G500)](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/g410_g510_ug_en.pdf) on page 30, see below for what they suggest with BIOS password issues such as the one you describe.

[image]

**Resource:** [*Lenovo User Guide (G500)*](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/g410_g510_ug_en.pdf)